# Manipulating a single row DataFrame object to a 6x6 DataFrame

Tags: python, dataframe

What I want to do is to do is pretty explained in the title, but for good measure here is my problem:

For the sake of the example let's say that I have a Google Form with 36 questions and I wanted to manipulate that row of answers to a dataframe using Python 3. Problem is that I get an error, but I'm getting ahead of myself. Here is what I've tried:

#

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

io_table=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((1,36)))
fctr_column=pd.DataFrame(np.random.random_sample((6)))

io_table=pd.DataFrame(io_table) #Convert list to DataFrame


io_t=io_table
factor=fctr_column
test=pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0,io_table.shape[1]+1):
    test=io_table.loc[0,i+1:i+6], ignore_index=True
    i=i+6
    print(test)
```

And, as I mentioned before, I got an error:

```
  File "path/to/temp.py", line 29, in <module>
    test=io_table.loc[0,i+1:i+6], ignore_index=True

TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable bool object
```

Now, I don't know what to do. Can anyone provide a solution?

> EDIT: Expected input and output
>   [image]

Comment: can you show expected output ?

Comment: @NagaKiran See my update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I got you right, but if you have a DataFrame with 36 values you can reshape it using something like in the following example:

```
import pandas as pd

a = range(1, 37)

df = pd.DataFrame(a).T

df.values.reshape((6,6))
#[[ 1  2  3  4  5  6]
# [ 7  8  9 10 11 12]
# [13 14 15 16 17 18]
# [19 20 21 22 23 24]
# [25 26 27 28 29 30]
# [31 32 33 34 35 36]]
```

Comment: It was a newbie mistake to think that I had to use a loop. Thank you, that'll do.